# Password protected cells aren't working after using Sorting Filter

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, google-sheets, protected

I recently had a problem whereby I couldn't sort my data within my worksheet due to my sheet being protected and also certain cells being password protected.

However I have now sorted that issue whereby I have highlighted the cells I need to sort and password protecting it - So when I need to sort, it will ask me for a password to unprotect this section.

When I do this however, after it sorts I want to change a cell that is initially suppose to be password protected - it changes without asking for the password - which is odd because the sheet is still protected.

Although the 2nd time I try it, it asks for a password!!

So my question is why doesn't it ask for a password the first time? & How do I get it to ask for a password the first time?

Here is the code which I altered in order to achieve this:

```
Option Explicit

Const sPassword As String = "Green"

Function ProtectSheet(bBoolean As Boolean, sSheetName As String) As Boolean
' -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Description:  (Un)protects a given worksheet & Workbook
' Inputs:       bBoolean: True = protect, False = unprotect, worksheet name
' Output:       Boolean (True/False)
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    If bBoolean Then
        Worksheets(sSheetName).EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions
        Worksheets(sSheetName).Protect Password:=sPassword, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowSorting:=True
    Else
        Worksheets(sSheetName).Unprotect Password:=sPassword
    End If

ProtectSheet = True

End Function
```

Any ideas?

Cheers! :)